# spinner data selection based on index value

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

i have set one spinner in my screen1 to select any of the spinner data from spinner and adding to my database. Now I have another screen2 of same spinner what i have in screen1 with same spinner data.  I want to show the data what is added in database, in first index of the spinner in layout2, without reputation of data in the spinner?

In **Screen 1**

```
organizer = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.orgainzer);
organizer.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Appoinment_Activity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,organizerspin));

// Spinner on item click listener
organizer.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
                getorganizer= organizer.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){}
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }
});
```

In **Screen 2** with same code what i mentioned above, i just code like this

```
editapporganizerspin.add(0,"Store_organizer");
```

if i do like this data is repeated in spinner

Comment: Please show the relevant code

Comment: we can't seen what you have done.

Comment: add if data not exist.

Comment: where i want to check if data not exist in screen 2 right

Comment: check where you are adding data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private int getIndex(Spinner spinner, String myString){

    int index = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<spinner.getCount();i++){
        if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).equals(myString)){
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Use this function after setting the adapter to compare the spinner values and swap it in index zero if the value is in spinner